# what features exactly the deep belief network of Geoff hinton extract from image while training his system for handwritten digit recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, image-recognition

hinton has created and worked on the [handwritten digit recognition system](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/MatlabForSciencePaper.html,) I want to know what feature exactly he extract from the image? I went through his work all I have seen is he converts the image into binary image after that I couldn't understand his way of feature extraction from image. Please help me out to understand this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deep learning is not about **feature engineering**. The whole point of Hinton work was **not to design any features**. System is trained on the **raw** image (just binarized), that's all. Everything else is done completely automatically in the deep training process (in his case, in multi-layered unsupervised data representation learning using stacks of Restricted Boltzmann Machines). What the system **learned by itself** was multilevel representation, based on geometrical features of the image on many scales (from corners, through lines to shapes).

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that it's very hard to figure out exactly what the system has leant, and that a lot of work is going into that at the moment

Comment: That is not correct. Automatic feature extraction is one of several fields of success for deep learning. 

The Science paper himanshu1496 cites is mainly about using autoencoders for an impressive form of dimensionality reduction though.
himanshu1496, have you listened to Hinton's own description of that research? He talks about it quite extensively in The Next Generation of Neural Networks <http://youtu.be/AyzOUbkUf3M>

Comment: @mirari yes I listened to it somewhat...and thanks to everyone for clarifying my doubt, I really appreciate your answers and opinions.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned earlier, there is subfield (or intersection with) of Deep Learning named Representation Learning (or Feature Learning). And these, indeed, try to learn meaningful representation of input data. It's especially useful in case of unsupervised learning when one can get a lot of unlabeled data, but obtaining labeled data is expensive.

One of deep learning models dealing with unsupervised feature learning is AutoEncoder (basically Neural Network with some constraints predicting it's input). In nearly all of papers on AutoEncoders you can find pictures like these (picture from [Stacked Denoising Autoencoders: Learning Useful Representations in a Deep Network with a Local Denoising Criterion](http://www.dmi.usherb.ca/~larocheh/publications/vincent10a.pdf)):[image: Learned features]

What does this picture mean: suppose you have a NN with image raw pixels (in this case it's corrupted by some noise, remember about constraints!) as it's input layer and predicting the same image (that is, it has as many nodes in the output layers as there are in the input layer, but now they aren't corrupted). Then you have some neuron in the hidden layer which is connected to all input nodes, that is it has one parameter for each pixel. Combining all these parameters together we get another image, which serves as a visualization of learned features. Basically, what that hidden neuron does is filters input image to extract one specific feature. We'd like filters to expose some variation and structure in order to be useful (that's why case a in the picture is bad and b and c are better).